# Hang in NtUserPeekMessage; am I nuts in insisting this should not occur?

Tags: .net, winapi

I've received multiple dumps from a malfunction inside a virtualization environment where the application just hangs up with Windows that say (not responding). The vendor of the virtualization environment thinks its an application problem despite the fact the customer can't reproduce the hang on an actual client machine but can repeat it almost on demand on the virtualization environment.

The minidump files show the same hang; the GUI thread is dead-stopped with NtUserPeekMessage (via winforms Application.DoEvents) as the top of the stack.

The application code looks as follows (pseudocode):

```
    while MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, new[]{eventhandle}, false, INFINITY, 0x4FF) != 0
        Application.DoEvents()   ;; HANG HERE
```

Stack top:

```
win32u.dll!NtUserPeekMessage() + 20 bytes
user32.dll!PeekMessageW() + 254 bytes
System.Windows.Forms.Ni.dll!(no symbol)
[Managed to Native Transition]
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.WIndows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessagLoop()
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner()
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop()
[Function given above]
```

Application.DoEvents does not actually appear on the stack; looks like its tail-called out.

The application is written in 99.9% managed code and hasn't had a heap corruption bug in over a decade.

Am I right that this should never happen?

New information 6/29/21 (may invalidate the extant answer):

The SetParent() call when used on windows without the WS_CHILD flag does not in fact attach input queues. I was able to observe on my own machine that AttachThreadInput() does in fact yield an error when trying to remove the non-extant attachment; however no error is observed on site, which means that something is attaching input queues that shouldn't be.

Comment: Having `PeekMessage` on top of the stack is indicative of a UI thread that is responding, not hung.  Can you see the arguments passed to `PeekMessage()` ?  Showing argument values in the call stack should be an option when debugging a minidump.

Comment: Also, did you retype that stack trace by hand?  `FPushMessagLoop` is spelled wrong...

Comment: Possibly related: https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2018/02/19/the-mysterious-ui-hang-which-resolved-itself-after-20s/

Comment: The link on that page to @RaymonChen's blog is broken, but here's the new location: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130607-00/?p=4143

Comment: So: are you creating a parent/child or owner/owned relationship between windows created in different threads?  Or is the virtualization platform doing so?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, that exists. Got any incite?

Comment: I would have expected a hang in GetMessage; found myself confused by the hang in PeekMessage which the documentation suggests returns immediately.

Comment: Show function arguments didn't work on the PeekMessageW call.

Comment: You're going to need to look at the stack trace of all threads which are sharing a message queue.  PeekMessage is hanging here because it can't get the lock for the message queue because another thread is holding it.

Comment: NtUserPeekMessage() is about 2 orders of magnitude more expensive than anything else you do in this loop, give or take.  In other words, out of 100 minidump captures, 99 of them will show it active in NtUserPeekMessage.  So you don't know anything yet, other than the wait is not being signaled.  That's nothing unusual.

Comment: @HansPassant: Ah. We know it's deadlocked though. Nobody's using any CPU.

Comment: PeekMessage returns immediately if there's a posted message at the top of the queue, but it can also do things like dispatch sent messages (and so will block until that returns).

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Correct, but it's deadlocked not spinning. We have the top of the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to multiple online sources including the very trustworthy Raymond Chen's Old New Thing, all message queue functions become blocking synchronous operations when multiple threads are attached to the same input queue.

Exposition here:

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130607-00/?p=4143

This developer did the debugging legwork to discover that hangs on this exact stack trace were caused by attached input queues.

- https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2018/02/19/the-mysterious-ui-hang-which-resolved-itself-after-20s/

I surmise that `PeekMessage` needs to acquire a mutex for the shared input queue... a mutex currently being held by another thread.  Contention for synchronization objects can cause poor responsiveness all the way up to outright deadlock.  To debug further, you'll have to take a look at what the other threads who share the same input queue are doing.

Comment: Direct FollowUp; does another SetParent drop the attached input queue? If true, this would shorten the search space.

Comment: @Joshua: I can't imagine that it would, because there could be multiple parent/child or owner/owned relationships between the same two threads.  It is possible however to use an explicit call to `AttachThreadQueue` to break the attachment relationship.

Comment: So you have indeed answered my question. I went back and manually detached the thread with AttachThreadQueue and the deadlock still occurs on site. Oh well.

Comment: @Joshua: Did you check the return value from `AttachThreadQueue` to make sure the detach succeeds?  How confident are you that you identified all threads to which yours was attached?  Also I'm not sure of the mechanism that causes the queues to become attached after a relationship is established -- it's possible the mechanism is "self-healing" and resists attempts to detach.

Comment: I added a call to AttachThreadQueue to detach the thread after SetParent(handle, 0); but I kind of suspect the real problem is in a 3rd party dll loaded into our process by the hosting environment.